# Arvixe web host - Spring MVC project not finding urls

Tags: spring, api, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have created an API using Spring.It runs perfectly at localhost. The problem is when I deploy the WAR file onto Arvixe (tomcat included). It won't get past the welcome file. All the other urls are not found - "404 Not Found". For example if I type 
    http://mylocaldomain.com:8080/restapi/listInstitutions/123/213/123 into the browser it returns the following JSON object :

```
{"message":"You do not have permission for this      domain","error":true,"comment":null,"notifications":null,"users":null,"diagnose":null,"institution":null,"notification":null,"patient":null,"picture":null,"user":null,"comments":null,"diagnoses":null,"institutions":null,"patients":null,"pictures":null}
```

But when I do the same thing with the deployed API on Arvixe (http://www.prespetkov.com/RESTapi/listInstitutions/123/123/213) I get "404 Not Found"

The mapping I am using is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listInstitutions/{appkey}/{uId}/{tokenValue}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Has anyone experienced the same problem or familiar with the hosting service?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Form the following response, it would appear that their shared tomcat instances will only work with jsp's!

http://forum.arvixe.com/smf/general/servlet-deployment/

Which I find kind of ridiculous.  What good developer will do that?